# How to export a model function from a controller to a view in Laravel 4

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to display some data from my database that is dependent on some input from the user.  I am using an ajax request to get the data, send it back to a function in my controller, and then export it back to my view.  I would like to collect this data and display it without going to another view (I just hide the previous form and unhide the new form).

Here is the relevant code:

Javascript:

```
$('#submit_one').on('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        if(! $(this).hasClass('faded')) {


        var fbid = $("input[name='like']:checked").val();
//variable to be collected is fbid


        request = $.ajax({ 
        url: "http://crowdtest.dev:8888/fans/pick_favorite", 
        type: "post", success:function(data){}, 
        data: {'fbid': fbid} ,beforeSend: function(data){
            console.log(data);
        } 
        });

        to_welcome_two();
        }

    });

function to_welcome_two()
{
    $('#welcome_one').addClass('hidden');
    $('#welcome_two').removeClass('hidden');
}
```

Controller functions:

```
public function pick_favorite() {

            $fbid=Input::get('fbid');

            return Artist::specific_artist($fbid);

        }
```

public function getWelcome() {

```
        return View::make('fans.welcome')
        ->with('artists', Artist::artists_all())
        ->with('favorite_artist', Artist::favorite_artist())
        ->with('pick', FansController::pick_favorite());

    }
```

Model function:

```
public static function specific_artist($fbid) {
        $specific_artist = DB::table('artists')
                        ->where('artists.fbid', '=', $fbid)
                        ->get();

        return $specific_artist;

    }
```

The view is on the "welcome" page.  My question is how do I display the model data in my view and make sure it is printing out the correct data from the fbid input?

I tried something like this:

```
@foreach($pick as $p)
    <span class="artist_text">{{$p->stage_name}}</span>
    <br>
    <span class="artist_city">{{$p->city}}</span>
@endforeach
```

but this is not printing out anything.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i see lots of issues here.

### Server side:

`public function pick_favorite()`.... what does it do? it just returns some data.

in `public function getWelcome() {` , you wrote, `FansController::pick_favorite()`. supposing both are the same method, you are accessing a static method whilst the method is non static. you are getting an error for this but you are not seeing it because you didn't define `fail()`.

and i don't see what the point of declaring a method which does nothing else then a model call which you can do directly.

e.g let's say i have a `fooModel`

```
public function index(){}
```

in controller, i can just write,

```
public function bar()
{
  $model = new fooModel;
  return View::make(array('param1'=>$model->index()));

}
```

or if i declare `index()` method in **fooModel** as static, then i can write,

```
public function bar()
{
    return View::make(array('param1'=>fooModel::index()));
}
```

### Client side:

now in your javascript,

```
$('#submit_one').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    if(! $(this).hasClass('faded')) {


    var fbid = $("input[name='like']:checked").val();
//variable to be collected is fbid


    request = $.ajax({ 
    url: "http://crowdtest.dev:8888/fans/pick_favorite", 
    type: "post", success:function(data){}, 
    data: {'fbid': fbid} ,beforeSend: function(data){
        console.log(data);
    } 
    });

    to_welcome_two();
    }

});

function to_welcome_two()
{
    $('#welcome_one').addClass('hidden');
    $('#welcome_two').removeClass('hidden');
}
```

why it should print any data? you didn't asked the script to print **anything**. where is your `.done` or `.success` param in your code?

If you look at your console, you'l get lots of php errors, i am almost sure of.

an advice, you need to lear some basics. e.g. jquery ajax call.

```
a basic ajax call can be 

    var request = $.ajax({
url: "script.php",
type: "POST",
data: { id : menuId },
dataType: "html"
});
request.done(function( msg ) {
$( "#log" ).html( msg );
});
request.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
});
```

implement it in your code and then see what errors it throws.

### Conclusion:

1st one will be (supposing rest of your codes are ok) the *static* error. if you want to call it as static, declare it as static. but a static function in controller? i don't see any purpose of it.

and then start the debug. your problem is both client and server side. deal one by one.

Comment: you can see I have the success param in my ajax code.  It exports the fbid fine.  But what I want is to be able to get the other data associated with this fbid.  I am getting no errors.

Comment: i don't see where is the `success` function.

Comment: type: "post", success:function(data){}, 
    data: {'fbid': fbid} ,beforeSend: function(data){
        console.log(data);
    }

Comment: could you please answer my question as to if there is a way to take this fbid variable, and apply it to a Model function to get other data (without changing views)?

Comment: i missed the `success:function(data){}`. the problem is indention here. 2nd, you are not doing anything with the data. as for your question above, i didn't get the question. can you rephrase it?

Comment: The fbid data, that I send with ajax back to my controller.  I would like to use that to get the output of another function, and output those results to my view.

Comment: i got your question. what i am not getting is, what is the proble you are facing?

Comment: I do not know how to get that data to my view based on that fbid?

Comment: actually you are already sending dada to the views. you only can't see it because it is AJAX request and __you haven't written anything to output on success__. write something to do on `successs` and it will do exactly. i.e. write the `success: function(data){alert(data)}`

Comment: Can I include my model function in that and pass the data to the function?  And get an output I can print?

Comment: you mean to say you want output from two different model methods?